# Extracting data from json object?

Tags: jquery, jsonp, json.net

In follwoing ajax call im getting the data in json format but in for each loop it does not extractin the data it skips the loop and moves ahead as if there is no data but while debugging it shows the data as .....

```
d:"[{"EmailCount":55,"DateAdded":"\/Date(1372651200000)\/"}]" //This is what shows //while debugging


jQuery.ajax({
                url: 'Dashboard.aspx/GetMailCountDateWise',
                type: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify({ frmDate: frmDate, eDate: eDate }),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("Worked");

                    var result = JSON.parse(data);
                    var series = { addData: [] };
                    $.each(result, function (itemNo, item) {
                        series.addData = itemNo;
                    });
});
```

so guys please help me how to extract this data thanks in advance

Comment: what is the data you r getting in response...
just provide the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use `JSON.parse`. `dataType: "json"` does that for you already.

Comment: i have removed the  JSON.parse but still it skipping the each {} loop ? thanks for the help.

Comment: @maddy what's the output of a console.log(data); after the alert? Just to make sure, you did use `data` instead of `result` in the `$.each` after you removed the parse, right? :)